# how can i get the value of a wordpress post's 'excerpt' for use in a plug in?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm embedding some important info into all my posts excerpts, and I'd like to use that string in a plug in i'm writing. I'm pretty new to php and wordpress so this may be obvious but I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate any help.

Comment: provide code you tried

Answer (score 0):

You need to make object and make it in global variable like

```
global $obj;
```

and you can use this object in plugin

Answer (score 0):

Add filter

```
function new_excerpt_more( ) {
return 'Custom String';
 }
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

works with

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```